# Angular to ASP.NET Core API - The JSON value could not be converted to System.String

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, angular12

Using ASP.NET Core 5 I have the following Controller and Models:

```
[HttpPost("users/{userId:int:min(1)}/confirm-email")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(Request request) {
  Response response = await _service.Send(request);
  return Ok(response);
}

public class Request { 
  [FromRoute] public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  [FromBody] public String Token { get; set; }
}

public class Response { }
```

On Angular I am calling the API using:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

var userId = 1;

httpClient.post<Response>(`${this.url}/users/${userId}/email/confirm-email`, { token: "test" } , { headers: headers });
```

On the Controller I get the `UserId` value but then I get an error for the token:

```
The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $
```

And the Key on the ModelState is not Token but `$`. For `UserId` the key is `UserId`.

I have no clue why this happens ... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I’m reading this wrong the routes are different.

```
users/{userId:int:min(1)}/confirm-email
```

Is not the same as what you are posting to

```
`${this.url}/users/${userId}/email/confirm-email`
```

The route doesn’t have /email/confirm-email. It is only confirm-email.